# Switch changes ON-OFF when scrolled in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

I have a ListView with a switch. Whenever I turn the switch ON and scroll down and scroll it back up, the switch changes to the turned OFF state.

Comment: you need to use ViewHolder for save state of switch...

Comment: @ChiragSavsani as you can see in my code I'm already using Viewholder. But it still not working. I think there's something wrong and missing in the code. Specifically this part. if(checkedItems.indexOf(accountList.get(position).toString()) >= 0)

Comment: @Cheskandroid where's your `onChange` listener?

Comment: @Sufian Ive added it to the code. Kindly check.

Comment: @Cheskandroid `SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();`. Hmm.

Comment: Post your Logcat. It's hard to know what you mean by `I get error in "indexOf"`.

Comment: @Sufian yes as I said how can I get all the tickedItems and put it in the condition.

Comment: @Sufian it says indexOf is undefined.

Comment: You didn't get it still? You're initializing a new array every time your `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called. Check [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) and see if there's a method `indexOf`.

Comment: @Sufian yes I get but I tried using indexOfKey but not working. Can you help me with my code please.

Comment: @Cheskandroid Can you post code?. Better to use SparseBooleanArray

Comment: @Cheskandroid have you tried my updated solution?

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your custom adapter..

// THESE TWO METHODS ALLOWS SCROLLABLE WITHOUT SWITCHES BEING TURNED ON/OFF WHEN VIEWS ARE RECYCLED
    // these methods in fact tell the adapter to not recycle the rows  so might slow down process

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect!

Comment: Worked for the switch in Recyclerview. By adding getItemViewType()

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem with `ListView`s. Try this

```
if(checkedItems.indexOf(accountList.get(position).toString()) >= 0) {
    holder.switchItem.setChecked(true);
}
else {
    holder.switchItem.setChecked(false);
}
```

You are initializing checkedItems right before you are using it. Its currently empty. How can do a indexOf when there is nothing in it.

This should solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm getting error in "indexOf" part it says undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: Yes this is my problem how can I get all the ticked items and put it in checkedItems? I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

`SparseBooleanArray` doesn't have any method named `indexOf`.

If you just want to store checked states, I'd recommend you to use `ListView`'s built in method `setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)`.

In your `getView()`, you can see if a position is checked (or in your case, your switch's state being ON or OFF) like below:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)parent;    //get the listview
listView.setItemChecked(itemPosition, true);    //set position as checked
listView.isItemChecked(position);    //check if position is checked (switch is ON)
```

Make sure you call this on your `ListView`:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

### Update 1:

In your code:

1. after `holder.switchItem = (Switch)     convertView.findViewById(R.id.switchItem);`, add this code:

   ```
   final ListView listView = (ListView)parent;
   //add listener
   holder.switchItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           listView.setItemChecked(position, isChecked);
       }
   });
   ```
2. replace `holder.switchItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchItemOnCheckedChangeListener);` with:

   ```
   //restore switch state
   holder.switchItem.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));
   ```
3. remove the following code:

   ```
   SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
   if (checkedItems.indexOf(accountList.get(position).toString()) >= 0) {

       holder.switchItem.setChecked(true);
   }
   ```

### Update 2:

This my how my adapter looks like:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 50;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return String.valueOf(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;
    final ListView listView = (ListView)parent;
    if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.switch1 = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        holder.switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                listView.setItemChecked(position, isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.switch1.setText(getItem(position));
    //restore switch state
    holder.switch1.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is how I'm setting my listview in my `ListActivity`:

```
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Tried this but it isn't working. Can you refer in my code please. What I only want is to be able tick the switch ON or OFF to remain like that even when I scroll down or up.

Comment: I change my code and now the switch won't even turn ON. Where should I put holder.switchItem.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));

Comment: Switch's state doesn't change to ON when you click? Or does is not get restored?

Comment: It doesn't change when I click. It wont let me change it.

Comment: Just updated my answer a bit. Make those changes and if it still doesn't work, update your question with your latest code.

Comment: Are you sure this line isn't causing this problem `holder.switchItem.setEnabled(nickRequired);`? Also, in `listView.setItemChecked(position, true);`, replace `true` with `isChecked`.

Comment: No. I tried removing holder.switchItem.setEnabled(nickRequired); also but still won't work. Replaced true with isChecked nothing happened. Don't you think it needs if else statement?

Comment: @Cheskandroid don't see why you'd need an if-else if you're doing what I wrote. For me, it's working as expected. Try again and mark this answer if it works, or add latest code snippet in you question :)

Comment: @Cheskandroid if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.