# Switch changes state when scrolling Listview

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement, toggle

I have a listview that has two switch/toggle button items. I customized the first switch item's settext to "No" when its OFF and "Yes" when its ON. And left the second item settext on default value text (ex. ON/OFF). Whenever I scroll down and up my listview switchitem changes its state. How can I maintain the switch state to original value? Help please. I don't know where is the exact problem in my code but I think the problem is in getview. See code below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.det_item_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.drawerItemIcon =  (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic1);
        holder.drawerItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic2);
        holder.switchItem = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.drawerItemIcon.setImageResource(drawerItems.get(position).getIcon_Id());
    holder.drawerItemName.setText(drawerItems.get(position).getName());

    holder.switchItems.setTag(drawerItems.get(position).getKey());
    holder.switchItems.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(drawerItems.get(position).getValue()));

    if (drawerItems.get(position).getKey() == Globals.DRAWER_LOCKCARD){

        holder.switchItems.setTextOn("Yes");    
        holder.switchItems.setTextOff("No");

    }


    holder.switchItems.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchItemOnCheckedChangeListener);

    holder.switchItems.setVisibility(drawerItems.get(position).getTag().equals("SWITCH") ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch changes ON-OFF when scrolled in Listview Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107932/switch-changes-on-off-when-scrolled-in-listview-android)

Comment: It is considered rude to repeat your question. Instead, improve your question if need be. If the answer doesn't help, let it known by posting a comment below it. It will inform the answerer that it didn't work and they may update it to make it solve your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Set a state of button/switch button and put a check like this. problem solved and remember to add notifyDataSetChanged(); after changing state of button.

```
if (profileActivationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) 
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_border);

            activeInactivestateBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active1);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you do in the Listener of Switch? Did you update the state of switch into **drawerItems**? Try this in Listener of Switch:

```
drawerItems.get(position).setValue("True/False");
```

By the way, why you have to use String instead of Boolean to save the state?